# Jquery button click event not working after adding jquery keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, virtual-keyboard

I try to get user input from a textbox using jquery keyboard.js.  If I omit the virtual keyboard code its work fine.

URL : https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki

Here is my textbox and button:

```
<input type="text" name="pnr" id="txtpnr" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter PNR Number" maxlength="10">
<button type="button" name="btnCheckpnr" id="btnCheckpnr" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Get current status</button>
```

I have include header file as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.keyboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

JavaScript code for virtual keyboard:

```
$('#txtpnr').keyboard({
        layout: 'custom',
        customLayout: {
            'default' : [
                '8 9 {a} {c}',
                '4 5 6 7',
                '0 1 2 3',
                '{bksp}'
            ]
        },
        maxLength : 10,
        restrictInput : true, 
        useCombos : false,
        acceptValid: true,
        validate: function(keyboard, value, isClosing){
            return value.length === 10;
        }
    }).addTyping();
```

Code I use for button :

```
$('#btnCheckpnr').on('click',function(){

        $('#flag-0').hide();
        $('#flag-1').hide();
        $('#flag-2').hide();

        if($('#txtpnr').val() == '' || $('#txtpnr').val().length < 10){

            $(".help-block").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            $('#txtpnr').focus();

        }else{

            $('#big-loading').show();
            $("*[name^='flag']").hide();
            $('#pnr-info').hide();

            $.ajax({
                'method':'POST',
                'url':'backEnd/jsonProcess.php',
                'data':'pnrno='+$('#txtpnr').val()+'&RequestType=checkpnr',
                success: function(getPnrStatus){

                    $('#big-loading').hide();

                    if(getPnrStatus == '0'){
                        $('#flag-0').show();
                    }
                    else if(getPnrStatus == '1'){
                        $('#flag-1').show();
                    }
                    else if(getPnrStatus == '2'){
                        $('#flag-2').show();
                    }
                    else if(getPnrStatus == ''){
                        $('#flag-2').show();
                    }else{
                        $('#pnr-info').show();
                        var pnrinfo = getPnrStatus.split('#');

                        $('.pnr').empty().html(pnrinfo[0]);
                        $('.journy').empty().html(pnrinfo[1]);
                        $('.trainname').empty().html(pnrinfo[2]);
                        $('.trainno').empty().html(pnrinfo[3]);
                        $('.class').empty().html(pnrinfo[4]);
                        $('.brdfrom').empty().html(pnrinfo[5]);
                        $('.bkpoint').empty().html(pnrinfo[6]);
                        $('.brdto').empty().html(pnrinfo[7]);
                        $('.chartinfo').empty().html(pnrinfo[8]);
                        $('#passenger-info tbody').empty().html(pnrinfo[9]);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

After add value through virtual keyboard the button click event not working.
How to I solve this? I have use bootstrap 3 css framework.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? I don't think it's likely that the virtual keyboard would change anything on unrelated input elements, so the most likely problem is that you made a syntax error when you added the call to `.keyboard`.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: console : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).keyboard(...).addTyping is not a function

Comment: here the another project links: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Virtual-Keyboard-Plugin-Keyboard.html

Comment: I can't find `.addTyping()` in the documentation at the site you linked to.

Comment: document :http://goo.gl/OfLvql

Comment: The syntax in the documentation is `$('#keyboard').keyboard(...).addTyping(...)`, implying that `addTyping` is a separate plugin. Maybe it's bundled with `keyboard` and needs its own `<script src="...">` tag.

Comment: visit: http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/

Comment: do you check js files such as : jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.min.js or jquery.keyboard.extension-all.min.js

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.js"></script>
This script is missing. addTyping() is part of it.

Comment: @Murali Add that as an answer and I'll vote it up! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.js"></script>
```

This script is missing.

addTyping() is part of it.